# Is there a way Bytecode matches with etherscan verification process validating Smart Contract

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, developer-tools, nft

Trying to validate a Smart Contract but keep getting ByteCode error as Etherscan can't match the correct one.

In Solidity everything works perfect but unable to validate in Etherscan.

Contract address: 0xa788612af215b661ed064895b34fcb620866c377

Error message:

**Compiler debug log:**
Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI
Found the following ContractName(s) in source code : **Address**, **Cloudy**, **Context**, **ERC1155**, **ERC1155Supply**, **ERC165**, **IERC1155**, **IERC1155MetadataURI**, **IERC1155Receiver**, **IERC165**, **Math**, **Ownable**, **Strings**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.8.2/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.8.2/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.8.2/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155Supply.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";



contract Cloudy is ERC1155, Ownable, ERC1155Supply {

    uint256 constant SleepyPinkDragon = 1;
    uint256 constant ThickCloud = 2;
    uint256 constant BlackHairPelicanCloud = 3;
    uint256 constant Superhuman = 4;
    uint256 constant Rattle = 5;

    mapping (uint256 => string) private _uris;

    constructor() ERC1155("https://arweave.net/sJa3zzrBzb2ejG_96_dzv_Jt9IdTdLNMbquxwa0Q/clo.json")
    {
        
     _mint(msg.sender, SleepyPinkDragon, 22, "");
     _mint(msg.sender, ThickCloud, 5, "");
     _mint(msg.sender, BlackHairPelicanCloud, 5, "");
     _mint(msg.sender, Superhuman, 3, "");
     _mint(msg.sender, Rattle, 3, "");
    }


  function uri(uint256 _tokenId) override public pure returns (string memory) {
        return string(abi.encodePacked("https://arweave.net/sJa3zzrBzb2ejG_96_dzv_Jt9IdTdLNMbquxwa0Q/clo", Strings.toString(_tokenId),".json"));
    }


    function setURI(string memory newuri) external onlyOwner {
        _setURI(newuri);
    }


    function mint(address account, uint256 id, uint256 amount, bytes memory data)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        _mint(account, id, amount, data);
    }

    function mintBatch(address to, uint256[] memory ids, uint256[] memory amounts, bytes memory data)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        _mintBatch(to, ids, amounts, data);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address operator, address from, address to, uint256[] memory ids, uint256[] memory amounts, bytes memory data)
        internal
        override(ERC1155, ERC1155Supply)
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(operator, from, to, ids, amounts, data);
    }
}
```

I used the Solidity flattener and copy and paste everything in the Etherscan Verify and Publish option. Still getting that Bytecode unable to match error.

example: I get a very long binary number

```
ByteCode (what we are looking for):
60806040523480156200001157600080fd5b506040518060800160405280604881526020016...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI` generally indicates that your submitted source code does not match the one generated on chain.

This is typically due to having different Solidity [compiler settings](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compile.html) on Etherscan vs when you deployed it, such as Solidity version, optimisation runs.

Would you be able to double check on your compiler settings if they match ?

Comment: Thanks I wanted to add to your point using the CONTRACT VERIFICATION - ETHERSCAN I can't seem to input a Selected Network it shows (VM NOT Support) this might be the main problem in allowing me to verify these Smart Contract. Thoughts....